# Japanese and Chinese first/last name detector

Tags: unicode, chinese-locale, cjk

Given two Unicode strings encoding a first and last name (in Japanese or Chinese), what would be the best approach to tell if the first/last name belongs is Chinese or Japanese?

For example, is it possible to tell if the following are Chinese or Japanese names?

```
任天堂
金城武
唐泽西
白川轩 
竹中宇
叶山明
林慧梦
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is impossible to tell the language of a string from just its raw character content alone.